# Replace icon in Expandable row of clr-dg-row-detail in clarity

Tags: html, angular, datagrid, vmware-clarity, clarity

I am making use of project clarity for my project and in this there is a data grid with expandable rows where i want to replace the icon that comes as default in the data grid

the default icon is as below

[image]

the icon i want to replace is below

[image]

Any help would be appreciated
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

At this time the expandable icon is specific to the ux/ui design for expandable rows and cannot be replaced.